# Parsing php interval_spec dateinterval into .NET Timespan object

Tags: c#, php, .net, vb.net, timespan

in php using interval_spec you can create a timespan using the format shown here:
http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php

eg. `$interval = new DateInterval('P2Y4DT6H8M');`

I have this format (`{"dateOffset:"P1D",...}` etc...) coming to my c# app in a json object and I wondered if there's an easy way to parse this into a .NET Timespan object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tumbleweeds?? So I wrote my own bulky method but it feels like it should be simpler than this:

```
public TimeSpan FromPhpDateInterval(string phpDateInterval)
{
    // Method to parse php's interval_spec (An interval specification)
    // The format starts with the letter P, for "period." Each duration period is represented by an integer value followed by a period designator. If the duration
    // contains time elements, that portion of the specification is preceded by the letter T. Here are some simple examples. Two days is P2D. Two seconds is PT2S.
    // Six years and five minutes is P6YT5M. See: http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php.
    DateTime now, then; now = then = DateTime.UtcNow;

    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+[A-Z]");

    string p = null;
    string t = null;

    if (phpDateInterval.StartsWith("P") && phpDateInterval.Contains("T"))
    {
        string[] split = phpDateInterval.Split('T');
        p = split[0].Substring(1);
        t = split[1];
    }
    else if (phpDateInterval.StartsWith("T"))
    {
         t = phpDateInterval.Substring(1);
    }
    else if (phpDateInterval.StartsWith("P"))
    {
        p = phpDateInterval.Substring(1);
    }
    else throw new Exception("Invalid interval_spec string format");

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p))
    {
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(p);

        for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++ )
        {
            string val = matches[i].Value;

            switch (val[val.Length - 1])
            {
                case 'Y': // Years
                    then = then.AddYears(int.Parse(val.TrimEnd('Y')));
                    break;
                case 'M': // Months
                    then = then.AddMonths(int.Parse(val.TrimEnd('M')));
                    break;
                case 'D': // Days
                    then = then.AddDays(int.Parse(val.TrimEnd('D')));
                    break;
                case 'W': // Weeks. These get converted into days, so can not be combined with D in php (makes no difference to us).
                    then = then.AddDays(int.Parse(val.TrimEnd('W')) * 7);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(t))
    {
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(t);

        for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
        {
            string val = matches[i].Value;

            switch (val[val.Length - 1])
            {
                case 'H': // Hours
                    then = then.AddHours(int.Parse(val.TrimEnd('H')));
                    break;
                case 'M': // Minutes
                    then = then.AddMinutes(int.Parse(val.TrimEnd('M')));
                    break;
                case 'S': // Seconds
                    then = then.AddSeconds(int.Parse(val.TrimEnd('S')));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return then.Subtract(now);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XmlConvert to convert to .NET TimeSpan

```
TimeSpan myTimeSpan = XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan("P2Y4DT6H8M");
```